# Embeding along with editable image in Word Document 2007

Tags: microsoft-word, images, microsoft-word-2007

I got stuck in a Word document file where I have to embed a picture. I want that picture to be browsable, which means, if a user wants to change the image, he/she should be able to change the picture by simply clicking on that portion where the picture has been loaded.....

I can simply insert the picture but was not able to make it browsable for changing the image....

Please help me to sort out this problem.....

Word Document file looks like :
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable Developer mode. Add Picture Control Word 2007

[image: add Picture Control Word 2007]

Disable Developer mode. Change picture Word 2007

[image: Disable Developer mode. Change picture Word 2007]

Way 2. OnClick or DoubleClick at pictogram.

[image: OnClick or DoubleClick at pictogram]

After change.

[image: picture Word 2007 After change]

Enable Developer tab Word 2007

[image: Enable Developer tab]

## Word 2007 compatibility mode.

Select picture.

[image: Word 2007 compatibility mode. Select picture.]

Compatibility mode. Drag&drop `windows explorer` selected image to `Word 2007` selected picture.

[image: Drag&drop <code>windows explorer</code> selected image to <code>Word 2007</code> selected picture]

Drag&drop result.

[image: Word 2007 compatibility mode. Change picture.]

## Word 2007 compatibility mode. Developer mode.

[image: Word 2007 compatibility mode. Developer mode. Image change and settings.]

## Word 2013

Add Developer tab.

[image: Word 2013 Add Developer tab.]

OnClick insert pictures.

[image: Word 2013 OnClick insert pictures]

Open pictire files dialog

[image: [Word 2013 Open pictire files dialog]

Comment: I don't see what added value the developer tab would provide. Why use a picture control when you can just insert a picture?

Comment: @teylyn If the document was a writer for yourself, it is easier of course your way. The thing is that this document will be used by multiple users. When they accidentally delete the picture and insert it the wrong way and will call you late at night ... I think the difference in this.) If I give you a template document, prefer it as little as possible could change or mess up. In a pinch you can make them two and allowed the removal of controls and banned. It was nice to hear the question from you. Thanks.

Comment: In Word 2010, when I insert a picture control, it [has a button to browse an image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/4AVGW.png) (seem exactly what OP's looking for). I wonder if it is different in Word 2007?

Comment: @AlvinWong See: Way 2. OnClick or DoubleClick at pictogram. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not quite sure what exactly you mean by "browsable", but to change an embedded picture, right-click on the picture and select "Change picture" from the context menu.

[image]

Or select the image and clic "Change picture" on the Picture Tools ribbon

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer...But,There is no any option "Change Picture"....

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your comment. Does your ribbon look different?

Comment: Just Check it out...It's not available in compatibility mode...Is there any similar option for compatibility mode?

Comment: If you are working with compatibility mode, it would be a good idea to mention that in your question, so you don't send people off searching for solutions that you won't be able to use. The "Change Picture" command is not available in compatibility mode. If you need the document to be compatible with earlier versions of Word, then you have to use the tools available with Word 2003 and earlier. There is no quick and easy way to change a picture in Word 2003 and earlier. You have to delete the existing picture and then insert a new one. ...

Comment: The reason for this is a completely new architecture of how a Word document is built and where/how the building blocks are stored. This new way enables new commands like "Change Picture", but if backwards compatibility is required, this new functionality cannot be used, of course.

Comment: @LolCoder See `Word 2007 compatibility mode` at my answer.